# Программа-тест

Tags: delphi, алгоритм

Здравствуйте!

Мне нужно написать программу-тест на Delphi. Но нужен не просто линейный тест, а с ветвлением. То есть, чтобы следующий вопрос зависел от предыдущего ответа. Помогите, пожалуйста, какими-нибудь ссылками на похожие разработки!

Спасибо!

Comment: Дерево или case of пробовали?

Comment: Тест человека или тест кода?

Comment: Пока еще ничего не пробовала. Пока собираю советы у опытных людей.

Comment: Тест человека. Ну если на пальцах, то вопрос и три варианта ответа, скажем. Только каждый следующий вопрос задается не один и тот же при любом ответе, а варьируется. То есть, если пользователь нажмет "Да", то появится один вопрос. А если нажмет "нет", то другой

Answer (score 3):

Проще всего редактор правил сделать - считыванием информации из файла. Продумайте заранее кол-во максимально возможных вариантов ответа.
Пишите в одну строчку:
idвопроса, текст вопроса, текст ответа 1, текст ответа 2,..., текст последнего ответа, idвопроса на который переходим по первому ответу, idвопроса на который переходим по второму,..., idвопроса на который переходим по последнему.
Если вариантов ответов меньше максимального - заполните пустые варианты например кодом 0.
Вариант ответа, по которому мы должны завершить тест пометим как -1. 
И реализуем следующий алгоритм.:

1. Элемент списка
2. Считываем информацию из файла в аналогичный массив
3. Текущий вопрос = 1й вопрос в массиве
4. Пока Текущий вопрос не равен -1 делаем:
5. Показываем текущий вопрос
6. Показываем все варианты ответа, где код ответа не равен 0
7. Считываем ответ пользователя
8. Текущий вопрос = id_вопроса на который мы должны перейти по выбранному пользователем варианту ответа
9. Переходим на шаг 3

Answer (score 2):

Заинтересовал меня этот вопрос и я решил сделать маленькую программулинку в пример. Тут многа букав =/

начну издалека: не надо разводить политосрач, это просто мой взгляд на решение задачи.
Это полет моей фантазии, такая базовая заготовка,  которую можно, при желании, развить дальше.

А теперь по делу:

программа считывает данные из ini файла, и на их основе создает дерево. в дереве каждая ветка является вопросом. В зависимости от ответа на вопрос (да или нет) выбирается следующий вопрос. Для программы не имеет значения количество ветвлений дерева. У класса вопрос есть параметр YesNo, его можно использовать для проверки правильности ответа.

пример ini файла:

```
[Questions]
0=0
1=0
2=0
3=0
4=1
5=1
6=2
7=2
8=3
9=3
10=4
11=4
12=5
13=5
14=6
15=6
16=7
17=7
18=8
19=8
20=9
21=9
[QuestionsText]
0=Вопросы
1=aaa
2=bbb
3=ccc
4=ddd
5=eee
6=fff
7=ggg
8=hhh
9=iii
10=jjj
11=kkk
12=lll
13=mmm
14=nnn
15=ooo
16=ppp
17=qqq
18=rrr
19=sss
20=ttt
21=uuu
[YesNo]
0=0
1=0
2=0
3=0
4=1
5=0
6=1
7=0
8=1
9=0
10=1
11=0
12=1
13=0
14=1
15=0
16=1
17=0
18=1
19=0
20=1
21=0
```

Структура ini файла:

```
Questions:
```

ключ - идентификатор вопроса (не должен повторяться)
  значение - родитель вопроса (т.е. вопрос предшествующий этому)

```
QuestionsText:
```

ключ - идентификатор вопроса (должен соответствовать ИД из таблицы Questions)
  значение - текст вопроса

```
YesNo:
```

ключ - идентификатор вопроса (должен соответствовать ИД из таблицы Questions)
  значение - тут можно экспериментировать, как душе угодно

Для начала описываем класс вопросов:

```
unit QuestionClass;

interface

type
  TQuestionClass = class
  private
    QuestionID        : integer;
    QuestionText      : string;
    QuestionYesNo     : integer;
  public
    Constructor Create(ID: integer);
    Procedure Free;
    Property ID     : integer read QuestionID;
    Property Text   : string read QuestionText write QuestionText;
    Property YesNo  : integer read QuestionYesNo write QuestionYesNo;
end;

implementation

Constructor TQuestionClass.Create(ID: integer);
begin
  inherited Create;
  self.QuestionID:= ID;
end;

Procedure TQuestionClass.Free;
begin
  inherited Free;
end;

end.
```

Теперь, собственно, код приложения:

```
type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    TreeView: TTreeView;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  private
    NewNodeChild  : TTreeNode;
    NewNodeParent : TTreeNode;
    ParentNode    : TTreeNode;
    ChildNode     : TTreeNode;
    IniFile       : TiniFile;
    QuestionList  : TStringList;
    TextList      : TStringList;
    YesNoList     : TStringList;
    { Private declarations }
    procedure LoadTree;  // процедура загрузки дерева из .ini файла
    procedure Test;
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

uses
  QuestionClass;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  self.Test;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  self.LoadTree;
end;

procedure TForm1.LoadTree;

  procedure BuildTree(Parent: TTreeNode);
  var
    i, i2: integer;
  begin
    for I := 1 to QuestionList.Count - 1 do
      begin
        if TQuestionClass(Parent.Data).ID = IniFile.ReadInteger('Questions', QuestionList[i], 0) then
          begin
            NewNodeChild:=  TreeView.Items.AddChildObject(Parent, IniFile.ReadString('QuestionsText', TextList[i], ''), TQuestionClass.Create(StrToInt(QuestionList[i])));
            TQuestionClass(NewNodeChild.Data).text    := IniFile.ReadString('QuestionsText', TextList[i], '');
            TQuestionClass(NewNodeChild.Data).YesNo   := IniFile.ReadInteger('YesNo', YesNoList[i], 0);
          end;
      end;
  end;
begin
  // Создаем объект ини файла
  IniFile := TIniFile.Create(ExtractFilePath(Application.ExeName)+'Ini.ini');
  // Создаем стринглисты
  QuestionList  := TStringList.Create;
  TextList      := TStringList.Create;
  YesNoList     := TStringList.Create;
  // Заполняем стринглисты значениями из ини файла
  IniFile.ReadSection('Questions', QuestionList);
  IniFile.ReadSection('QuestionsText', TextList);
  IniFile.ReadSection('YesNo', YesNoList);

  // Создаем корень дерева
  NewNodeParent:=  TreeView.Items.AddObject(nil, IniFile.ReadString('QuestionsText', TextList[0], ''), TQuestionClass.Create(StrToInt(QuestionList[0])));
  TQuestionClass(NewNodeParent.Data).text   := IniFile.ReadString('QuestionsText', TextList[0], '');
  TQuestionClass(NewNodeParent.Data).YesNo  := IniFile.ReadInteger('YesNo', YesNoList[0], 0);

  // Строим дерево
  BuildTree(NewNodeParent);

  // освобождаем стринглисты
  QuestionList.Free;
  TextList.Free;
  YesNoList.Free;
end;

procedure TForm1.Test;
var
  Count: integer;
  Children: integer;
  I: Integer;

    procedure GoTest(Parent: TTreeNode);
    var
      Child: TTreeNode;
    begin
      // задаем вопрос, и в зависимости от ответа выбираем следущий вопрос
      if MessageDlg(TQuestionClass(Parent.Data).Text, mtConfirmation, [mbYes, mbNo], 0) = mrYes then
        Child:= Parent.GetNextChild(Parent.getFirstChild)
      else
        Child:= Parent.getFirstChild;
      // если есть еще вопросы
      if Parent.HasChildren then
        // Продолжаем тест
        GoTest(Child);
    end;

begin
  // Количество первых вопросов
  Count:= 0;

  // Получаем корень дерева
  ParentNode:= TreeView.Items.Item[0];

  // Получаем первый вопрос
  ChildNode:= ParentNode.getFirstChild;
  // Если вопрос есть, то
  while Assigned(ChildNode) do
    begin
      // Пытаемся найти следующий вопрос
      ChildNode:= ParentNode.GetNextChild(ChildNode);
      // Увеличиваем счетчик первой линии вопросов
      inc(Count);
    end;

  // Выбираем рандомный вопрос из первой линии
  Children:= Random(Count);

  // Находим полученный вопрос в дереве
  ChildNode:= ParentNode.getFirstChild;
  for I := 0 to Children - 1 do
    ChildNode:= ParentNode.GetNextChild(ChildNode);

  // Запускаем тест
  GoTest(ChildNode);
end;
```

Comment: TreeView я использовал для удобства отображения/редактирования вопросов

Comment: Ух, как подробно! Спасибо огромное... Я думала несколько проще будет

Comment: я с этим вашим ini файлом не сталкивалась. Как-то не работает у меня эта штука. Мне нужно просто txt файл, отдельно лежащий и из него чтобы считывалось. И структура в виде дерева чтобы была. Ну сейчас попробую отредактировать как-нибудь под себя

Comment: при работе с ини файлами нет ничего сложного. Ini-файл отлично подходит для работы с деревьями, так как данные в нем имеют четкую структуру, и можно настраивать связи между ними. ОЧЕНЬ грубо говоря, получается своеобразная реляционная бд, а программа выступает ее системой управления :)

Comment: В таблице Questions в левой части указаны уникальные номера всех вопросов, в правой части указан родитель вопроса (вышестоящий вопрос). получается разветвление. в таблице QuestionsText указаны тексты вопросов. В таблице YesNo указаны правильные варианты ответа для каждого вопроса. Варианты ответа могут быть какие угодно. Как можно заметить все таблицы в ini-файле связаны между собой по номеру вопроса.

Answer (score 0):

Пусть есть таблица-опросник: 10 заходов по 10 вопросов каждый.

Простой вариант. Случайное перемешивание. Для каждого испытуемого свои вопросы (независимо от ответа).

1. Создаем таблицу с номерами вопросов в исходной таблице.
2. Случайным образом перемешиваем вопросы для каждого захода.
3. Проводим тест, извлекая вопрос из исходной таблицы на основании, номера вопроса.

Дерево вопросов.

1. Создаем дерево с номерами вопросов в исходной таблице.
2. На каждом уровне ветви дерева определяются возможными вариантами ответов.
3. Проходим тест, спускаясь по ветвям вниз.

Почитать про деревья в Delphi: [серия статей](http://sdb.su/programmirovanie/delphi/page,6,244-fundamentalnye-algoritmy-i-struktury-dannyx-v-delphi-chast-8-iz-14.html).

Comment: Суть я уловила! Низкий поклон! Единственное, что плохо: я недавно узнала, что  в программе должен быть встроен редактор правил (или идти отдельным файлом в комплекте).

Answer (score 0):

Создать базу данных для теста, где будут указываться вопросы и ссылки на другие последующие вопросы. Выдавать вопросы рандомно, а дальше двигаться по ветке ссылок вопросов. Такой тест несложно писать, если все структурировать и делать правильную нормализацию таблиц.