# Как написать тестировщик на Delphi?

Tags: delphi, тестирование

Нужно написать тестировщик, сохраняющий тесты (в любом виде - txt, формы и т.д., главное, чтобы работало) и их же создающий, эдакий MyTestX. Интерфейс не имеет значения, главное, чтобы пользователь смог создавать, открывать и проходить эти тесты. У кого какие идеи, как это реализовать?

Comment: Если хотите, то можете принять ответ, или дождитесь идеи получше.

Comment: Если устроит C++ и Qt посмотрите https://sourceforge.net/projects/keduca/ раньше работало, но давно не обновляется

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Тут идей может быть несколько - всё зависит от того, что именно от программы тестирования Вы хотите. Можно реализовать на основе БД, если Вам нужно чтобы пользователи, прошедшие тест сохранялись, а также другая информация, относящаяся к тесту. Если не на основе БД, то через типизированные файлы. Примерно так: есть объект-запись (и файл этого же типа), в котором вопрос, количество вариантов ответа, и 2 массива: первый массив строк - варианты ответов, а второй - логический массив - в котором указаны правильные ответы. Можете посмотреть пример в книге М. Е. Флёнова "Библия Delphi" - там в последней главе есть вариант программы тестирования (я его не набирал).

Comment: Спасибо большое,жаль не могу отплатить репутацией)

Answer (score 1):

Я [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/81073/13336) написал пример программы-теста. Сама программа работает, но нет сохранения результата. Сохранение результата легко можно добавить.

Comment: @kff, там была ссылка на hashcode, это не внешний ресурс. :)

Comment: @VenZell Упс... Пардон. Не посмотрел...